# How to rename files with same name, but in different subdirectories in a Git repo?

Tags: git, svn

I migrated a part of an old SVN repository to Git, now I am at the whole thing. The problem is that this old repository was only used by people only using Unix style operating systems, and they were not careful enough to prevent name clashes due to case (in)sensitivity, so I have files like:

```
/some/where/FOO.BAR
/some/where/foo.bar
/at/a/different/location/FOO.BAR
/at/a/different/location/foo.bar
```

The file names are always the same (they simply copied the same file to a whole bunch of different locations). Now I want to rename all `FOO.BAR` files to `FOO1.BAR`. I already read Git's documentation that I have to use `filter-branch` with `tree-filter`, but this always works from the root of the repository.

Do I really have to use `git filter-branch` for every folder with this name clash or is there a shortcut?

Comment: Your goal is to rename all files named `FOO.BAR` or only the ones in `/at/a/different/location` ? In any case, `git filter-branch` is fine if you wish to change the whole history.

Comment: I want to rename all `FOO.BAR` to `FOO1.BAR`, in all directories.

Comment: I figured that a manual rebase is better here because the conflicting files are referenced in several other files. I am currently doing this.